# how to download page from source code

Tags: vb.net

i need to download page from source code..for example

```
<span id="businessNumOnMap" class="resultNumberOnMap" style="display:none;"></span><span><a href="/len/aapproximatch%20search/285295.php" onclick="loadBusinessInfo('0', '285295'); return false;" class="businessName">Cellini's Italian Restaurant</a>
```

i want to download the "/len/aaproximat...php"..i didnt find the suitable regex for it..and i need to download that page..can anyone help?

im using vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebClient.DownloadString method for downloading. If you haven't found a suitable expression to extract that "Span" from the source, then build you own.

Answer (score 3):

Normally it's not recommended to parse HTML with a regex, with the exception if this is a simple page that you know the format of, the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is often recommended for this purpose instead.

Be aware though, if you're parsing this from a page that's on the internet, the site in question might have T&Cs for the usage of their data that you might need to follow to stay legal.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to download the php file itself with all the codes and not the only html codes? If it's in that case it's not possible

Comment: i want to download just the php file..do u have any suggestion?

its in <a href="/len/aapproximatch%20search/405195.php"onclick="loadBusinessInfo('4', '405195')>

i just to download the /len/aapproximatch%20search/405195.php